# Best electronics book for a physics graduate

Tags: reference

I'm a physics graduate; I want to learn some electronics so I'm searching for a book which gives an fair overview of electronics (components, analog circuits, digital circuits...) suitable for me (not like electronics demystified or electronics for dummies).

Comment: What you really need is a physicist who's learned electronics to answer. Most regular EEs haven't been down this path so it's difficult to interpret what would be a good book for you.

Answer (score 5):

Back in the day [The Art of Electronics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_art_of_electronics) was popular with fellow physics students. [One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Horowitz) of the authors is a physicist.

It depends what you want to do. I just bought an Arduino, and am toying around with that. It turns out that I find lots of good information on the web. There are tutorials, videos, ebooks, datasheets, etc.

Comment: Still popular and used in our basic electronic laboratory in undergrad as of 2011

Comment: Why is this book so good? Does it use calculus to deal with electronic circuits? I need something like that and I am physicist myself. I hate dummbed down books without derivations...